# How to plot time series data from SQLite database

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotting, databases, sql

I am trying to plot time series data by accessing the SQLite database. I successfully connect the database by coding the below script,however, i couldn't figure out how to plot the time series data from `.sqlite` file.

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by the db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn

def main():
    database = r"E:\Data\SINCAL_Models\AusNetData\20180128_PQV\pq.sqlite"

    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)
    with conn:
        print("Database connected:")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The database file is shown in attached picture. I am trying to plot the yellow highlighted variables to get the plot like [here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU874&tbm=isch&q=time%20series%20in%20python&chips=q:time%20series%20python,g_1:matplotlib:Pj4qC4ik7vs%3D&usg=AI4_-kSFoyin8EmjIR1xo3Fj945YkiJbrA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif57b4kOnlAhUX8HMBHfOGCBwQ4lYILCgB&biw=1920&bih=920&dpr=1#imgrc=FlaSesXuZ3AnsM:)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using python this will be very easy for you :). 
I presume the table name as it is not clear to me and a db file can have several.

You can use pandas to access the data using your connections.

```
import pandas as pd
def fetch_table_data_into_df(table_name, conn):
    return pd.read_sql_query("select * from " + table_name, conn)
```

This will give you a pandas Dataframe- they are very well suited for plotting.

I usually use `pylab` directly but I think this should also work:

```
df = fetch_table_data_into_df("NameOfTable", conn)
df.plot("READ_TIME", "VALUE")
```

Let me know if you need more information :).

Here is the entire code (using yours and mine) as well:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import pandas as pd
import pylab


def fetch_table_data_into_df(table_name, conn):
    return pd.read_sql_query("select * from " + table_name, conn)

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by the db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn

def main():
    database = r"E:\Data\SINCAL_Models\AusNetData\20180128_PQV\pq.sqlite"

    TABLE_NAME = "pq_data"
    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)
    with conn:
        print("Database connected:")
        df = fetch_table_data_into_df(TABLE_NAME, conn)
        # reading what you want to do, I presumed you want 
        # to plot per measuremnt
        for measurement in df.MEASUREMENT.unique():
            df[df.MEASUREMENT == measurement].plot("READ_TIME", "VALUE")
            pylab.savefig(f"{measurement}.png")
            pylab.clf()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @Thank you for useful answer,but still i am unable to plot. The arror is attached here https://filebin.net/u41uc853h9tq4luc/error.png?t=xyald2rs. Also the SQL data table is also attached here. https://filebin.net/u41uc853h9tq4luc/SQL_data.png?t=xn0d4yqa

Comment: I updated the answer to help with the missing piece

Comment: Thank you for great answer. Let me try the updated code.

Comment: @EI Burro. This time the code successfully plot the graphs but the y-axis is quite strange. Also the legends for 3 unique variables (P,Q,V) in table, it prints "VALUE" as legend for very graph as shown here https://filebin.net/c2kujy1w8lgq9n7m.

Comment: You can try to use pylab.ylim(bottom = YMIN, top = YMAX) amd if you give the .plot the argument label = measurement it should replace it. Also you can control the legend posisiton with pylab.legend()  - but i feel this is becoming another question about data visualization ;)

Comment: Thank you for great answer. If i need to create to create the distribution fitting for variable "VALUE"  in main code, how can i shuffle the above script? Distribution fitting like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python?lq=1